# Append child contents of selected div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a div of id=instafeed and a div of id=slick-track, I am trying to use appendTo to append the children of the instafeed div to the slick-track div.

Starting out the two divs should have the following content...

```
<div id="instafeed">
  <div><img src=""></div>
  <div><img src=""></div>
</div>

<div id="slick-track"></div>
```

The appendTo should result in the following...

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>

<div id="slick-track">
  <div><img src=""></div>
  <div><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I have only been able to figure out how to append the entire instafeed div into the slick-track div, when I only want the children. How can I got about appending the children only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`.contents()`**](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method to get the children elements and append it to `$('#instafeed')`.

```
$('#slick-track').append($('#instafeed').contents());
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wwooeomv/)

---

If you use [**`.contents()`**](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), all children elements including text nodes will be appended.

On the other hand, using [**`children()`**](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will *not* append text nodes.

> The [**`.contents()`**](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [**`children()`**](http://api.jquery.com/children/) methods are similar, except that the former includes text nodes as well as HTML elements in the resulting jQuery object.

[**Comparison Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/y5m988nj/)

Comment: Yes @Josh Crozier, and also it returns comment nodes plus it can access the html of iframe if it is in the same domain. Thank you for sharing knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like,

```
$('#slick-track').append($('#instafeed').children());
```